# How can I drop the elements of this dictionary into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, explode

I have a dictionary inside of a Pandas DataSeries

```
data    {'Huobi': [0.01, 0.036944, 0.033314, 0.023049,...
Name: dataMap, dtype: object
```

Here is a link to the full text
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/armaniallie93/files/home/armaniallie93/fundingdataMap

How can I drop the elements inside the dictionary into rows in a DataSeries? The explode function does not work because it is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the contents of this dictionary to rows, you should first access the row with the dictionary (`s.data`), then use `s.data.items()` to get the `key` and `value` pair that will be used to create the new Series. The previous step results in a `dict_item` which can then be converted into a list, after that, assign the first (and only) tuple of that list to `name` and `values`. These variables will then be used with `pd.Series` to create the named Series.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(
    index=["data"],
    data=[{'Huobi':[0.01, 0.036944, 0.033314, 0.023049]}],
    name="dataMap"
)
print(s)

name, values = list(s.data.items())[0]
s_out = pd.Series(name=name, data=values)
print(s_out)
```

Output from *s*

```py
data    {'Huobi': [0.01, 0.036944, 0.033314, 0.023049]}
Name: dataMap, dtype: object
```

Output from *s_out*

```py
0    0.010000
1    0.036944
2    0.033314
3    0.023049
Name: Huobi, dtype: float64
```